# Send data to windows from iphone using Xamarin

Tags: ios, windows, xamarin, networking, tcp

I'm trying to write an IOS app using Xamarin that sends data to PC using TCP. I want it to do this with Cable or WiFi. I have been researching around the net for sometime now. But couldn't find any good tutorials. I'am aware that I should be using NSNet and Bonjour Windows SDK but I couldn't find anything more than that. Any suggestions or directions on how to achieve this would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xamarin then the more preferred choice would be to write things using System.Net.Sockets namespace. This way you can reuse the code with other C# clients, including Android (if needed).

Plenty of examples on TcpClient/TcpServer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did not think, that would work on Xamarin. I will give it a try.